# get list of Queries Per URL by google analytics or search Console

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I want to generate a report like this:

[image]

I could not find the custom report in google Analytics or search console. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Search Console allows you to see individual search queries per landing page, so if you have only a few landing pages, that may be a viable solution. Bring up the performance report in Search Console and select the Pages report. You can thing just click on a page and see all of the data relating to that one landing page.

Analytics does not allow you to cross-reference landing pages with search queries.

There is a solution to this to build a report that includes a full list of search queries alongside the landing pages, and that is to use [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/). It's free and it really easy to link your Analytics and Search Console data.

1. Create a new report.
2. Choose Google Search Console as the data source.
3. Authorise access to the data using your Google credentials.
4. Select the correct site.
5. Choose URL Impression as the Table, and Web as the Property Parameter, then click Add.
6. It'll pop up a default table for you, you need to now change the dimensions included in the table.
7. With the table selected, the right hand column will give you the options. Change the current dimension to Landing Page.
8. Click Add Dimension and select Query.
9. The default metric should be already URL Clicks, but if not you can select that under Metric.

The settings should look like this:

[image: Google Data Studio table settings]

You can then format the table as you wish, setting the default number of rows, adjusting the dimensions of the table to suit. By default the table will be sorted by URL Clicks, from largest to smallest.