# How to redirect old domain URLs without the old website?

Tags: domains, google-search, redirects, url

My client deleted their website and do not have a backup of it on the old domain. I need to redirect their old domain URLs in Google Search to the new domain. I have access to their old domain and have setup hosting but there is no website.

I tried just a regular domain redirect, but it is not redirecting URLs, just the root domain redirects.

How can I do this?

Comment: We'll need to know a little more about what web server or platform you're using, but in general you'd collect a list of URLs indexed for the old site in Google from [Google Search Console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/138223/get-list-of-queries-per-url-by-google-analytics-or-search-console) or by using another crawling tool and then setup up `301` redirects for each old URL to the new URL.

Comment: Yea this is what I did. Worked great!

Comment: Glad it worked. If you like, you can write an answer below based on what you did and then accept it when you get a chance - that way you'll earn some reputation points here so you can comment and do other things on this site in the future and the question will be considered resolved - thanks!